# How can I concatenate multiple excel sheets in a single file to one single file with an extra column that contains original sheet name?

Tags: python, excel, concatenation

I have an excel file with over one hundred sheets.  Each sheet has the same columns with information.  I have concatenated all the sheets in one single file.

#### Script

```
single_file = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx',sheet_name=None),ignore_index=True)
single_file.to_csv('single_file.csv')
```

The script works fine.  The thing is I would like to add a column that identifies each row of information with the name of its original sheet.  Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Comment: Please format the question properly atleast. It helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
single_file = pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
single_file = pd.concat([sheet.assign(identifier=i) for i,sheet in single_file.items()])
```

Here we are using the idea that all sheets can be accessed by iterating (using `items()`) over the dictionary of dataframes.

Comment: Thanks! I will make it work.  I am getting an error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'assign'

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to save the `pd.concat` for the very end of the script.

You've read in the file with `sheetname = None` which creates a dictionary of sheet names as the key, and the dataframe as the value.  Loop over each sheet and add your label column first, then concatenate.